# Check if there are unnamed columns in dataframe then return indications in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a small dataset `df` which copied from an excel file as follows, I need to check `if there Unnamed columns inside`:

```
    id  floor  Unnamed: 2     type
0    1     13         NaN   office
1    2     12         NaN   office
2    3      9         NaN   office
3    4      9         NaN   office
4    5      7         NaN   office
5    6      6         NaN   office
6    7      9         NaN   office
7    8      5         NaN   office
8    9      5         NaN   office
9   10      5         NaN   office
10  11      4         NaN   retail
```

Code:

```
lst = list(df.columns)

for x in lst:
    if 'Unnamed' in x:
        print('Unamed columns found')
    else:
        print('Normal')
```

Out:

```
Normal
Normal
Unamed columns found
Normal
```

In fact, when there are unamed columns, I want return `Unamed columns found`, otherwise returns `Normal`, which may need to modify the code like:

```
'Unamed columns found' if df1.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed') else 'Normal'
[x for x in df1.columns[df1.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]]
```

How could I modify the code above? Please note it's not necessary to loop and return multiple `Normal`.

Thanks a lot for your help at advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said in comment, try `f-string`

```
s = f'''{'Unnamed columns were found in your dataset' 
               if df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed:').any() else 'normal'}'''


In [96]: print(s)
Unnamed columns were found in your dataset
```

---

If you want number as in the comment, try this

```
m = df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed:')
s = f'''{str(m.sum()) + ' Unnamed columns were found in your dataset' 
                             if m.any() else 'normal'}'''

In [140]: s
Out[140]: '1 Unnamed columns were found in your dataset'
```

Comment: Sorry, my question may not be clear, for the example dataset, I only want to return an indication: `Unamed columns were found in your dataset`.

Comment: if there are multiple `Unnamed:..`, you still want print only one line `Unamed columns were found in your dataset` ?

Comment: Yes, one phrase is ok, maybe adding count the number of `Unamed columns`? e.g. `3 Unamed columns were found in your dataset`.

Comment: Thanks but if it's a normal dataframe as input, which means no unamed column in it, i want also it returns `normal`

Comment: there is an else to print `normal` when there is no `unnamed:..`

Comment: @ahbon: I edited to add solution with number as you mentioned in the comment. Check my updated answer